# Spring data @Transaction is not executed in order

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions, spring-repositories

My Service code likes below:

```
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void changeAuthorities(Long id, ChangeUserAuthoritiesRequest model) throws RecordNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findById(id);
        if (userOptional.isPresent()) {
            User user = userOptional.get();
            long result = userAuthoritiesRepository.removeByUser(user);
//            System.out.println(userAuthoritiesRepository.findByUser(user));
            model.getAuthorityIds().stream().forEach(authorityId -> {
                UserAuthority userAuthority = new UserAuthority();
                Authority authority = authorityRepository.findById(authorityId).get();
                userAuthority.setUser(user);
                userAuthority.setAuthority(authority);
                userAuthoritiesRepository.save(userAuthority);
            });
        } else {
            throw new RecordNotFoundException("User not found with id: " + id);
        }
    }
}
```

The code means "delete all records with the given id and then add again the new ones" (the new ones may be the same the old ones). 
My problem is method `userAuthoritiesRepository.removeByUser(user)` is not executed before new records are saved by `userAuthoritiesRepository.save(userAuthority)`. So the app raises the exception:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'user_authority_unique'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.user_authorities'. The duplicate key value is (1, 1).
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1535)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:467)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:409)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:219)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:199)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:356)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
    ... 177 more
```

Comment: Hi, you need to clarify the meaning and the grammar in this sentence : "The problem is that ... is not executed beforing new records saved by ... caused the exception:"

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#flush--

Comment: @JB Nizet, so everytime I call a JPARepository method I need call flush() ?. It works, but how I misunderstanding spring transaction. In some other projects I also call so many methods in a transaction and don't have the problem. Please clarify for me, thanks you!

Comment: Why would you have to call flush "every time"? You need to call flush() when you want some statements to be executed before others, and JPA can't figure it out by itself. That's quite rare. Very far from "every time". That has nothing to do with transactions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate JPA: @OneToMany delete old, insert new without flush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410868/hibernate-jpa-onetomany-delete-old-insert-new-without-flush)

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the `@Transaction` annotation or the order of execution of your code. Its just that the changes aren't pushed to the database. So ou are getting that error.

You will have to call the `flush()` method after the `removeByUser()` method call to push the changes to the database.

You can check [this link](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-remove-entities-persistence-context/) for understanding why it is needed