# Spring Data: How to update a List of childs with unique constraints

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, constraints

I am using spring-data to persist data to a mysql db.
I have a parent entity that contains a list of child entitys:

```
@Entity
public class Parent
{
    private Long id;

    @Unique
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private List<Child> childs;

    // Getter, Setter
}
```

and here is the child entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(
    uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "parent_id", "name" }) }
)
public class Child
{
    private Long id;

    @Unique
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    // Getter, Setter
}
```

In the database I have the same constraints active like in this two classes.
Now, I want to update the childs of the parent like this:

```
@Service
public class ParentService
{
    // ...

    @Transactional
    public Parent updateParent(String name, List<Child> newChilds)
    {
        Parent existingParent = parentRepository.findByName(name);
        existingParent.setChilds(newChilds);
        return parentRepository.save(existingParent);
    }

    // ...
}
```

But then the unique constraint (name + parent_id) for the child will fail, if they have the same name. How can I get sure, that the old childs are deleted before the new childs are persisted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use

```
existingParent.getChilds().clear();
parentRepository.save(existingParent)
existingParent.getChilds().addAll(newChilds);
```

because of ([Hibernate JPA: @OneToMany delete old, insert new without flush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410868/hibernate-jpa-onetomany-delete-old-insert-new-without-flush))

And if you are on default transaction behaviour, you can change

```
return parentRepository.save(existingParent);
```

to

```
return existingParent;
```

Loaded and then changed entities are automatically saved on transaction commit, so you are actually saving twice.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, creating a new list in the parent was not good and I can also remove the manual save of the existing entity object. I didn't knew that hibernate observes his models that complex, seems like I should study some more about hibernate/jpa.